# Django REST JSON API: how to include nested compound documents?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Using Django REST JSON Api, i.e. djangorestframework-jsonapi==3.1.0 and having the following data structure: parent, singleChild, manyGrandChildren (all just dummy names, singleChild means one-to-one relation, manyGrandChildren means one-to-many nested relation).

```
...
class Parent(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    included_serializers = {
        'singleChild': singleChildSerializer,
        'manyGrandChildren': manyGrandChildrenSerializer,
    }

    class Meta:
        model = models.Parent
        fields = [
            'field1',
            'field2', 
            'url',
        ]

    class JSONAPIMeta:
        included_resources = ['singleChild', 'manyGrandChildren']
...
```

My code does not work, because I cannot access manyGrandshildren on my response, which is something like http://host.com/api/parents/1/?include=singleChild,singleChild.manyGrandChildren
also please correct me if my url ?include= statement is not correct.

**How do I accomplish that?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To include grandchildren in the serializer, we need to define *included_serializers* and *included_resources* on the child serializers and include grandchildren there. In that case, we can access them from parent serializer. The naughty thing is the relationship. for one-to-many relationships we need to set *'manyGrandChildren_set'* as key for *included_serializers* and include it as *'manyGrandChildren_set'* field in *class Meta* fields.

example

```
class Child(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    included_serializers = {
        'manyGrandChildren_set': manyGrandChildrenSerializer,
    }

    class Meta:
        model = models.Child
        fields = [
           ...
           'manyGrandChildren_set'
           ...
        ]

    class JSONAPIMeta:
        included_resources = ['manyGrandChildren_set']


class Parent(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    included_serializers = {
        'singleChild': singleChildSerializer,
    }

    class Meta:
        model = models.Parent
        fields = [
            'field1',
            'field2', 
            'url',
        ]

    class JSONAPIMeta:
        included_resources = ['singleChild']
```

Comment: I'm trying to do something similar, but where the intermediate model is also M2M (e.g. `manyChildren` instead of `singleChild`). Happen to know if/how that might be possible?

Comment: I believe, this is connected to naming conventions: OneToMany uses __set in the end, many to many does not, as far as I remember.

Comment: @esmail did you find solution to your problem?

Comment: It's been a while since I touched this, but I believe you were correct; it was a matter of referencing like `*__set`.